# Boostrap's modal dialog, send information with AJAX jQuery doesn't working

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new in jQuery. I'm trying to creat a meme website, and i got stuck when i wanted to create the login/register page, using the boostrap's modal dialog. I want to make it work when someone press "Create Account" to pass all datas from inputs, into a AJAX, where they will be insterted into database.

Here is my code

```
<div id="deleteMessage" class="modal fade in" style="display: none; ">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">

                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title"><center>Sign Up!</center></h4>
                    </div>


                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <?
                            $errorid = $_GET['errorid'];

                            if($errorid == 1)
                                echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Scuze, dar acest nume de utilizator este deja folosit!</div>";

                            else if($errorid == 2)
                                echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Parolele nu coincid, te rugam sa le rescrii cu mai multa atentie!</div>";

                            else if($errorid == 3)
                                echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>E-Mailul scris este deja folosit de catre un alt utilizator!</div>";

                            else if($errorid == 4)
                                echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Trebuie sa accepti termenii si conditiile pentru a te putea inregistra!</div>";
                        ?>
                        <br>
                        <form action="register.php" method='POST'>
                        <fieldset>
                            <input type='text' name='username' class='form-control' placeholder='Username'>
                            <br>
                            <input type='password' name='password' class='form-control' placeholder='Parola contului...'>
                            <br>
                            <input type='password' name='password2' class='form-control' placeholder='Confirma parola'>
                            <br>
                            <input type='email' name='email' class='form-control' placeholder='E-Mail'>
                            <br>
                            <input type = 'radio' name='terms' value='1'> Accept <a href='" . $rewUrl->rewriteUrl(false, "terms") . "'>termenii si conditiile</a>
                        </fieldset>
                        </form>
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span> Inchide</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-warning" id="newDatssa"><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok'></span> Creaza Contul</button>
                    </div>  

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The button to show the modal dialog:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#deleteMessage">Sign Up</a>
```

And finally the jQuery code:

```
$(function() 
        {
            $("button#newData").click(function()
            {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "register.php",
                    data: $('form.contact').serialize(),
                    success: function(msg)
                    {
                        $("#deleteMessage").modal('hide');
                    },
                    error: function()
                    {
                        alert("failure");
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

What ever i've tried, i always get that "failure" message from the alert, and i don't know what to do, to pass the values into the ajax, any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: You could change the error function to `error: function(xhr, status, error) {
  var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
  alert(err.Message);
}` and tell us what's in the message...

Comment: I got an "undefined" error in alert's box.